# Jersey doesn't register my resource

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a very basic application using Spring Boot(2.0.0) and Jersey. Unfortunately when I try to call exposed endpoints I get error 404.

My code looks like this:

Main class:

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args )  {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Jersey config:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig{
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(FileResource.class);
    }
}
```

Resource:

```
@Component
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class FileResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/uploadfile")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition disposition) {
        System.out.println(disposition.getName());

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/foo")
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Maven dependecies:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

When I call:

```
GET /api/foo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
```

I get:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-03-27T08:37:13.926+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/foo"
}
```

The same happens for the second endpoint. In application logs I can find `Servlet .....JerseyConfig mapped to [/api/*]`
Does anybody knows what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what is wrong.

It turned out that in Jersey every resource must have `@Path` annotation on class level.
After changing my Resource to:

```
@Component
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/uploadfile")   // THIS IS MANDATORY ANNOTATION
public class FileResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition disposition) {
        System.out.println(disposition.getName());

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/foo")
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

it started working.